# Logarithm problem when simplifying without answering in decimals

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

I'm trying so solve the following problem:

$$\log(8) + \log(x) = 6 \, \log(5).$$

The answer is supposed to be "exact" so without any decimals and as simplified as possible.

However, the $6$ in $6 \log(5)$ gives me a hard time to do this.
Can anyone show me the way to solve this?

Comment: If $b, x > 0$, with $b \neq 1$, then $\log_b x^n = n\log_b x$.

Comment: How would you do this if the 6 weren't there? Can you do that with the 6 there?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig where did the b come from? I am sorry but I don't really understand what you are explaining :(

Comment: In that formula, $b$ is the base of the logarithm.  When the base is omitted, $b = 10$ or $b = e$, depending on the context.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Without the 6 i'd write 10^log(x) = 10^log(5)-10^log(8)... which is x=5-8

Comment: That's not quite correct. It's not true that $10^{a-b} = 10^a - 10^b$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig alright, yes the base should be 10. Is log b x^n= nlog b x a logarithm rule? Sorrys for the formatting, I don't know how to format it like a equation.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I see, what would be the correct way of solving this instead then?

Comment: As you now know from thesmallprint's answer, it is a [property of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Product,_quotient,_power,_and_root).  For help typesetting mathematics on this site, you can consult this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Welcome to MathSE.

Comment: Yes I see, I'll absolutly will look into that typesetting tutorial. What a powerfull tool this community is for learning those mathematical problems and their solutions, thanks :) @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the following rules of logarithms here:

1. $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$
2. $c\log(d)=\log(d^c)$

With these rules in mind, our problem reduces to $$\log(8x)=\log(5^6).$$ Now, we raise both sides to the base $e$, known as exponentiation (the inverse of logarithms) and we get $$8x=5^6,$$ from which, we use trivial algebra to get $$x=\frac{5^6}{8}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was not sure how to apply the 2nd rule in this situation like you did.

Comment: No problem whatsoever! Just keep at it and you'll eventually get there.

Comment: Just a quick question, shouldn't the c and d be switched on the right side of the equal sign in the second rule? Otherwise the rule implies: 6 log (5) = log (6^5) but you showed "log(5^6)

Comment: Ah, silly me - of course. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Just when I thought I was beginning to not understand again haha but good that that only was an spelling error in the rule, thanks for your help again!

Comment: Haha, sorry. My silliness must've confused you momentarily. It's good that you spotted it though! No problem at all though, pleasure's all mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\log 8 +\log x= \log 8x $$

$$6\log 5=\log 5^6.$$

Comment: This isn't really helping me understand how to solve my problem, atleast not for me who just can't get his head around logarithems :/

Comment: Just use that $\log A=\log B\iff A=B.$